# How many object files are there overall across all directories?

Tags: linux

How many object files are there overall across all directories?
May use 'find', 'xargs', 'file', and 'grep'

what is the command I should use?

Comment: what is the  command i should  use

Comment: I think the point is that you are supposed to figure that out, not random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have GNU `grep` and are using a shell with support for [“ANSI-C quoting”](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html),

```
grep -rlZ $'^\x7FELF' | grep -c $'\0'
```

will output the number of ELF object files starting from the current directory. You can specify paths to start from as arguments to the first command:

```
grep -rlZ $'^\x7FELF' /bin /usr/bin | grep -c $'\0'
```